# How to configure client for access with authsecret?

Tags: servicestack

I'm using the client and I need to call a service using authsecret parameter.
If I ad this param to the base url it give me a serialization error.

```
String baseUrl = AppConfig.GetAppApiUrl();
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl.AddQueryParam("authsecret","secretz123!"));
var c = client.Send(new ComuneRequest { Id = "A001" });
```

Using Fiddler I discovered that the request that the client generate is incorrect:

> POST
>   http://192.168.0.63:820/?authsecret=secretz123%21/json/reply/ComuneRequest

So, what I have to do to make the client create a request in a correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be sent as a Request Parameter (i.e. QueryString or FormData) which you can do using [HTTP Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) with:

```cs
var url = baseUrl.CombineWith(requestDto.ToUrl()).AddQueryParam("authsecret", secret);
var res = url.GetJsonFromUrl().FromJson<MyResponse>();
```

Otherwise since `AuthSecret` is not a property on your Request DTO you wont be able to send it as a Request Parameter in the Request Body, but you should be able to send the param in the Request Headers with:

```cs
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    RequestFilter = req => req.Headers[HttpHeaders.XParamOverridePrefix+"authsecret"] = secret
};
```